# Cannot type letters or numbers in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Suddenly today, I can no longer type letters or numbers into the editor in PyCharm 2018.2.2 Build #PY-182.4129.34. I can still type symbols such as [] and {} but letters and numbers appear when typed and then immediately are deleted.

I've checked that Vim emulation is off, the plugin is not even installed as far as I can tell. I've updated my Material Theme plugin. None of my settings have been changed since I last used PyCharm.

It's independent of what file I'm editing. I've also disabled my international keyboard. Read-only is turned off as well.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: broken delete/backspace key? :)

Comment: maybe it's a too obvious attempt, but did you try to restart your PC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When all else fails:

`file` -> `invalidate caches/restart`

Answer (score 5):

Try to deactivate Vim by  'Tools -> Vim Emulator' (Untick the option)