# pycharm: Cannot type in editor

Tags: pycharm

fter updating Pycharm, I can no longer type letters or numbers into the editor in PyCharm 2019.3. I can still type symbols such as [] and {} but letters and numbers appear when typed and then immediately are deleted.

I have already tried:
1.- disabling/uninstalling Vim emulator.
2.- checked INSERT key
3.- keymap-> Toggle/Insert assigned double click.
4.- Invalidate and restartcache.

I run out of ideas

Comment: Have you tried : `file` -> `invalidate caches/restart` as indicated here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194338/cannot-type-letters-or-numbers-in-pycharm?rq=1

Comment: yes. tried that.

Comment: Just solved. I have uninstalled some plugins: kite, and other other one related to [<>] brackets ( don't remember the name)..no sure which one caused the issue but i will leave it as it is for now.